# Creating PDF from certain UIView causes crashes

Tags: ios, pdf-generation

I have been trying  to save certain UIViews to a PDF, and in some cases it crashes.. Note in crashes on a particular UIView. in this code, the crash starts on `UIGraphicsEndPDFContext` am I doing something wrong here?.. that makes the error inconsistent on some UIViews?

```
   NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData,CGRectMake(0, 0, 0,0   ), nil);
        // Points the pdf converter to the mutable data object and to the UIView to be converted


        // draws rect to the view and thus this is captured by UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData
        [contentViews enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock: // Enumerate content views
         ^(id key, id object, BOOL *stop) {

             ReaderContentView *contentView = object;

             UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
             CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

             [contentView.theContentView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];

         }];    

        UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

The crash is in the first line

```
0x33e69884:  ldr    r2, [r0], #4
0x33e69888:  beq    0x33e6989c               ; strlen + 36
```

Thanks guys!